# DHCP server router vs PC

Tags: dhcp

I have a problem with DHCP implementation on embeded system, where DHCP Discovery packet with mandatory fields are sent but router (TP-Link) dont answer on it. With DHCP server on PC are all OK and IP are obtained everywhere. Have You any idea what is different on router DHCP server? Is able that router need more option fields like hostname, client id etc.? (but it is not mandatory.) I try 2 different TP-link routers.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found that TP-Link routers:

1) ignore some range of MAC address

2) DHCPOFFER packet is unicast and answer to unvalid IP address.